# How to get filename in log file using log4j?

Tags: java, log4j

I am using log4j for the first time.
According to a requirement, i want to display the name of the file in the log (same way as date is displayed) in the log file.

for example:

```
17:56:57,863 help INFO  [STDOUT] PropertyHandler-If
```

where `help` us the name of the file where `PropertyHandler-If` is written in `log.debug()`.

Also, I want different log file for all the exceptions pertaining to database.
Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you want to store the name of the file in the file? Doesn't the file name the name of the file.

Comment: Check this [post](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1109220), it seems very similar to your requirement.

Comment: The OP wants the name of the _class_ (or class file, maybe, in case several classes are defined there), not the name of the _log file_.

Answer (score 1):

You can define multiple appenders (one for each file) and set different loggers to use different appenders.  By using different Log objects, you have direct these to different files. e.g. a single component can have multiple `Log`s

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [PatternLayout](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) with the 'F' option: "Used to output the file name where the logging request was issued."

As @Peter Lawrey points out, you can use multiple appenders, in your case a specific [FileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.html) that logs for the database.